# Can you find the exact moment an ExceptionError takes place?

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm scraping some websites for products. I then import all the data into a CSV file. Some products might not present all the information that the other products do. For example, most products will have measurements, but the odd few don't. So those that don't need to be filled with blank data to make sure the rest of the data doesn't fall out of sync and everything stays in order.

An example of code where data falls out of sync:

```
for product in list:
    try:
        description.append(product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".description").text)
        measurements.append(product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".measurements").text)
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

So as you see, with this code, if measurements don't exist for that product, then it skips to the next product in the list, which then means the next measurement appended to the list is paired with the previous product that didn't have a measurement, thus falling out of sync.

So this is the code I have to prevent this:

```
for product in list:
    try:
        description.append(product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".description").text)
        try:
            measurements.append(product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".measurements").text)
        except Exception as e:
            measurements.append("N/A")
    except Exception as e:
        description.append("N/A")
```

This works, but in reality there are several / dozens of information on the product which I have to pull in. So having this nested set of 'try' and 'exceptions' can become really overcrowded and seems unnecessary.

My question is, is there any way to tell where an exception error occurs? That way I can just use one 'try' and 'exception' line of code and under the exception block, depending on where the error occurred, I can then append `("N/A")` to the correct list relevant to where the error occurred.

I thought about checking the length of each list before hand and checking the length again during the exception to identify which list failed to be appended, but wondering if there's a more simple in-built method in Python for things like this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to append something that you're not sure of, and since you are doing it multiple times you're getting undesirable results. Better is to split the code and prepare the values before appending them. E.g.:

```
# do not use reserved keyword list 
for product in product_list:
    r = {}
    locators = ['description', 'measurement',...]
    for locator in locators:
        try:    
            r[locator] = product.find_element...
        except Exception:
            r[locator] = "N/A"

    description.append(r['description'])
    measurement.append(r['measurement'])
    ...
```

Comment: SimpleNamespace error. The value of locator is not being assigned to the SimpleNamespace, rather 'locator' is being assigned and is being treated as the variable name, not the variables value. What to do?

Comment: @cap1hunna sorry about that. Let's just use dictionary, not SimpleNamespace. I have revised the code. Please see the edit.